# How to get the winapi id of a thread that has been created using the standard library?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, c++11

C++11’s standard library contains `<thread>` which allows threads to be created. However, the Windows api requires an ID for some functions ([PostThreadMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), namely). How can I get it?

remark: `std::thread::get_id()` doesn’t seem to work:

```
PostThreadMessage(m_thread->get_id(), WM_QUIT, 0, 0);

e:\documents\khook\khooker\hook_runner.cpp(129): error C2664: 'PostThreadMessageW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::thread::id' to 'DWORD'
```

Comment: Does `GetCurrentThreadId` work? Even from a different thread, you could use that from within the thread in question and store it, if it works in the first place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the member function [`native_handle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle). It provides the native thread handle. Then you can call `GetThreadId()` on it.

Comment: Note that `native_handle()` returns a `HANDLE` (`void*`) for the thread; you'll also need `GetThreadId()` to get the identifier from the handle to call `PostThreadMessage()`.

Answer (score -1):

The `thread::id` class only allows comparison between `id`s and an output. It does not provide a means to access the actual underlying `id`. You could try outputting it to a `stringstream` and then parsing it back in, I guess.

Comment: I don’t understand how a stringstream would help?

Comment: @Qdii, the ID knows how to print itself to a stream (for debugging). The implementation happens to just print its numeric value. Once you have the numeric value in a stringstream, you can read it back into a numeric type.

Comment: @RobKennedy: can I be certain that the `thread::id` is the same value as the windows api value ? (I thought it could be the value of an intermediary library, like, pthread).

Comment: Well, yes, but for that matter, so could `native_handle`. The "native" part only refers to the part not defined by C++. Once you're past that, "native" means whatever the implementation wants or needs it to mean. If the thread library is implemented directly in terms of the OS, then it's probably the OS handle and ID, but if there's another thread library in between, like pthread, then it could be a pthread-specific value. Either one counts as "native" from the standard C++ viewpoint. The `id` value is implementation-defined, so check your implementation.