# Cast std::thread as HANDLE to call TerminateThread()

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, c++11

Could it be posible to cast or convert a std::thread thread in C++ to a HANDLE in Windows?
I've been trying to manage threads in Windows with WINAPI functions for threads but I can't get it to work...

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

void Hi(std::string n){
while(true){
    std::cout<<"Hi :3 "<<n<<"\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
}

int main(void){

std::thread first(Hi, "zoditu");

first.detach();
getc(stdin);

//SuspendThread((void*)first.native_handle());
TerminateThread((void*)first.native_handle(), (unsigned long)0x00);
CloseHandle((void*)first.native_handle());

std::cout<<"No D:!!\n";
getc(stdin);

return 0;
}
```

But seems to do nothing because thread keeps spawning "Hi's" in the console... Could there be a way to "kill" it using WINAPI?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885215/how-to-get-the-winapi-id-of-a-thread-that-has-been-created-using-the-standard-li) answer your question?

Comment: @RonTang: I see no indication in the question that the program *needs* to be portable.  Most doesn't, after all.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Not really since I'm not asking for a thread ID, because I can't get a thread by it's ID in WINAPI. I'm asking how to convert the thread to a Windows HANDLE to pass it through the Thread functions in Win32. And I don't want it portable, my question is WINAPI related lol :P

Comment: Just add a `GetLastError()` call after the call to `TerminateThread()` and check the error value.  That said, could you explain why you want to call `TerminateThread()` in the first place?  It's almost always a poor choice.

Comment: When you called `first.detach()` you made `first` forget the thread handle (and any and all other information about the thread). Save the handle before calling `detach()`, or don't call `detach()` at all.

Comment: I'm not sure that you should try to convert it to a WinAPI handle because what if the implementation uses pthreads? `std::thread::native_handle()`.. "Returns the implementation defined underlying thread handle".

Comment: It's `int main()` in C++. Always check win32 calls for errors. You failed to do so.

Comment: @MrEric That's bad advice. One must check for error before calling GetLastError.

Comment: Of course, calling TerminateThread is the wrong thing to do. Graceful termination is what you need.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan True, but the above code isn't even doing that! Too many WTFs to mention in a single comment, honestly.

Comment: @MrEric What you are advising is as bad as the code here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is not a "bad advise". I'm just a curious young guy. Is it really bad to be curious and try to do some weird stuff just for FUN? This is not intented to be "perfect" or bad. I see you want to make corrections on everything but I asked for an answer, not for a "what you have to do" order cause looks like that and not like an advise.

I recognize that Interrupting a Thread is a bad idea but I'm just exploring new and "weird" stuff by my own. I just asked because I can finish a Thread with pthread in UNIX. Why not in Windows?

Comment: @Ramses suggesting that you call GetLastError without first check the return value is indeed bad advise. Given that you aren't an expert on Win32, wouldn't you like to learn?

Comment: @JamesAdkison I don't know if you put the "Duplicate" in this question, but my question has NOTHING to do with ID. Too bad it is marked as duplicate because if someone else has this question sometime, it will be referenced to a WRONG answer. Question is about Handle, not ID.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I'm not an expert and I want to learn

Comment: I didn't. For me, it clearly states "marked as duplicate by Harry Johnston, sashoalm, Deduplicator."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with using the value returned by `std::thread::native_handle()` directly with the Win32 API functions (i.e., a conversion is not required).

The following program works for me. *However*, it usually (always?) crashes if the thread is terminated while it is actively executing but works just fine if the thread is suspended before terminating. As you are aware and others have pointed out it is generally not a good idea to terminate a thread.

But *to answer your question* the Win32 API seems to work as expected without any additional conversions. The following program works for me.

#### Program:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

void foo()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "foo()\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::thread first(foo);

    bool isFinished = false;
    while (!isFinished)
    {
        char ch = ::getchar();
        ::getchar(); // Swallow the new line character

        if (ch == 'e')
        {
            isFinished = true;
        }
        else if (ch == 's')
        {
            DWORD result = ::SuspendThread(first.native_handle());
            if (result != -1)
            {
                std::cout << "Successfully suspended thread\n";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Failed to suspend thread: failure resson " << ::GetLastError() << "\n";
            }
        }
        else if (ch == 'r')
        {
            DWORD result = ::ResumeThread(first.native_handle());
            if (result != -1)
            {
                std::cout << "Successfully resumed thread\n";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Failed to resume thread: failure resson " << ::GetLastError() << "\n";
            }
        }
        else if (ch == 'k')
        {
            DWORD result = ::TerminateThread(first.native_handle(), 1);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Successfully terminated thread\n";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Failed to terminate thread: failure resson " << ::GetLastError() << "\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Unhandled char '" << ch << "'\n";
        }
    }

    first.detach();

    std::cout << "waiting to exit main...";
    ::getchar();
    std::cout << "exiting...\n";

    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample Output (comments added by me):

```
foo()
foo()
foo()
foo()
s
Successfully suspended thread // This was successful since 'foo()' is no longer printing
r
Successfully resumed thread // This was successful since 'foo()' is again printing
foo()
foo()
foo()
foo()
s
Successfully suspended thread // Worked again
k
Successfully terminated thread // Says it works...
r
Successfully resumed thread // Termination must have worked because resuming did not cause 'foo' to start printing
e
waiting to exit main...
exiting...
```

Comment: The reason the thread ends is because when getchar() receives an Input, it passes through the code until it gets to `return 0;` which finished the main thread, making it to finish first thread too. Comment `std::cout << "Terminate? " << (::TerminateThread(first.native_handle(), 1) ? "success" : "failure"` and you will notice it's the same result. If you add `getchar()` before `return 0;` I will get back to the same problem...

Comment: @RamsesAsmush I'm not sure I fully understand what your comment. However, I updated the program in my answer. As far as I can tell everything works without any additional _conversions_.