# Reliably identify a thread in an independent process

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I'm trying to identify the thread ID of an independent process (e.g. test.exe), but I don't know how to do it since its ID changes each time the program is opened

Despite a lot of research, I couldn't find any way to do this

I noticed Visual Studio (debug) giving me the "location" of a thread and that seemed like a reliable way to identify it

Comment: There is no such thing as a memory address of a thread or a process. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: When I debug on Visual Studio, in the threads tab, I have a "location" which is marked

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you really trying to do?

Comment: I launch Visual Studio, I will put a screenshot

Comment: I'm trying to make a program that automatically suspends a thread when I run it, and for that I need to know its ID, I noticed that the "location" that is shown in Visual Studio is reliably to identify it

Comment: Threads don't have a memory address.  Threads have an ID.

Comment: @vnkx3 - Are you trying to suspend a very specific thread in a well known process. Do you control the code that runs in that process?

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought they had one, I'll rename my topic
My problem is that the ID is not stable and changes every time I open the software again

Comment: I'm trying to suspend a thread that I identified during debugging
I don't have access to the source code

Comment: There could be multiple threads running within the same process.

Comment: In my specific case it is a single thread (I was able to suspend it during the debug to check)

Comment: [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) can do this, so it's possible. That said, if Process Explorer can do this, you might as well use Process Explorer to suspend the thread.

Comment: I've used Process Explorer before but it was working badly because I need to suspend the thread as soon as it starts, that's why with Visual Studio's debugger I was able to do it without problems by putting a breakpoint

Now I'm looking to create a program that does this automatically, without needing to debug

Comment: This sounds like very low-level, operating system-specific, highly technical API function. So: Step 1: study C++ for 5-7 years to gain medium to expert level understanding of C++, Step 2: study this operating system's low-level APIs, for another one or two years, in order to familiarize oneself with the fundamental concepts and low-level operating system details, Step 3: implement this function using low-level APIs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10885261/3871028

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Find a process and then find all threads in that process. WinAPI allows you to do it.

Comment: I have a code that lists all threads, but the thread IDs change every time I restart the program

Comment: If I can get the thread ID from the location shown in visual studio (5th column in the image), then I can identify my thread reliably (in my case there was only one, not several like in the picture)

Comment: You can write your own custom debugger that only does this one thing: identify the thread in question - (it's not clear to me how you do that now, do you know that a certain piece of code is only run by this one thread?) - set a break-point, then suspend the thread. It's not trivial but not rocket science either.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid might do it, if there's a window associated with the thread

Comment: I identified it by putting a breakpoint on each thread opening (then suspending them one by one)

And now i can reidentify it on visualstudio without breakpoint, by its "location", even when I close/reopen the program

What I would like to do is automate it without needing to run the debugger manually, if i can get the thread id in c++ then i could suspend it

Comment: @vnkx3 The "location" you are looking for is the entry point where a thread begins running code from. Given a thread ID/handle, you can use `NtQueryInformationThread(ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress)` to get the thread's entry point. There are ways you can be notified when a new thread is being created, and then you can look at its entry point to see if it matches what you are interested in.